# Elastic search - SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single node ES cluster.
I have created a new index with 10 shards that suppose to have 1TB of information.
So I have started to `reindex` part of the data into this new index and I got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception`.

```
I have restarted the docker container and I see the following.  
What Should I do?  
thanks  

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-12-13T14:35:28,155Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "607ed4606bec", "message": "path: /.kibana/_count, params: {index=.kibana}", "cluster.uuid": "zNFK_xhtTAuEfr6S_mcdSA", "node.id": "y9BuSdDNTXyo9X0b13fs8w" , 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:551) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:309) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:582) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:393) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.lambda$performPhaseOnShard$0(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:223) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$2.doRun(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:288) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:44) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:737) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-12-13T14:35:42,170Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataIndexTemplateService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "607ed4606bec", "message": "adding template [.management-beats] for index patterns [.management-beats]", "cluster.uuid": "zNFK_xhtTAuEfr6S_mcdSA", "node.id": "y9BuSdDNTXyo9X0b13fs8w"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-12-13T14:37:52,073Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "607ed4606bec", "message": "Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[entities][5]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "zNFK_xhtTAuEfr6S_mcdSA", "node.id": "y9BuSdDNTXyo9X0b13fs8w"  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are reaching your JVM memory heap size limit to solve the problem you can increase your docker memory size and try again.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think all shards failed related to memory. That was the root cause of the initial error. But i cant iorate it sice